# Using Moto Droid Car Charger with Samsung Galaxy Nexus

Tags: motorola-droid, charging, samsung-galaxy-nexus

I just upgraded my phone from the original Motorola Droid to the Galaxy Nexus. Both phones use the same micro USB port. Is there any reason I cannot use my Droid's car charger with the Nexus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the car charger I bought for my Moto Droid is unable to charge the Galaxy Nexus. It just does...nothing.

Answer (score 1):

It should work fine -- Micro-USB is Micro-USB.  The only possible caveat is the phone and charger may not negotiate high speed charging.  However, that's unlikely.

My wife and I have shared wall and car chargers between her old Droid, current Droid X, and my Incredible without any problems.

Comment: I tried using my wife's Droid car charger with my Galaxy Nexus and it did not charge. (The wall/USB charger works, though.)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was primarily concerned with "blowing up" my phone through a mismatch in voltages or something along those lines.

Comment: @AlEverett - Did it not work at all, or did it just provide a weak charge? I know the Nexus is seeing an issue where it can't maintain a charge when navigation is running.

Comment: USB is standardized 5v, but some devices may want higher amperage, and fail to charge, for example: http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/watt_to_know_about_iphone_ipad_power_adapters/

Comment: @NoBugs: There's a [USB Charging Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Charging_ports) for going over the standard 500mA max load (900mA for USB 3.0), though Apple is still using their own standard.  Pretty much every other modern smartphone should be using the USB Battery Charging Standard though.

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue with the actual car socket. Ensure that the fuse is intact, and that the socket is working fine.